# JavaScript import instead of require in an object

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

So let's say i have some code like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  Someclass: require('./lib/Someclass')
}
```

I can make it more es6

```js
export default {
  Someclass: require('./lib/Someclass')
}
```

But how would i replace the require with es6 syntax without setting a variable?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What's wrong with setting a variable?

Comment: I have many values in the object and setting a variable for each would be messy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should not default-export an object, but use named exports instead. So either

```
// re-export the whole namespace
import * as Someclass from './lib/Someclass';
export { Someclass }
```

or

```
// re-export the default export
export { default as Someclass } from './lib/Someclass';
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes i was looking for the second one

Answer (score 0):

[MDN lists](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) the following patterns for aggregating modules:

```js
export * from './lib/Someclass' // does not set the default export
export * as name1 from './lib/Someclass'
export { name1, name2, …, nameN } from './lib/Someclass'
export { import1 as name1, import2 as name2, …, nameN } from './lib/Someclass'
export { default } from './lib/Someclass'
```

Comment: Thanks! The last one was what i was looking for